# Is there a way to loop through a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

So I'm working with csv files and wanted to plot some graphs out of them. However, i couldn't find a way to get the info i needed directly from the Dataframe. The code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

```
path_main = '850566403_T_ONTIME.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(path_main, header=0, sep=",")
#remove columns and rows with nan
df1.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
df = df1.dropna(subset=['ARR_DELAY_NEW'])
```

the output of said Dataframe:

```
        YEAR  MONTH  AIRLINE_ID  DEST_AIRPORT_ID  ARR_DELAY_NEW
0       2015      2       19805            12892            0.0
2       2015      2       19805            12892            0.0
3       2015      2       19805            12892            0.0
4       2015      2       19805            12892            0.0
5       2015      2       19805            12892            0.0
     ...    ...         ...              ...            ...
429186  2015      2       19393            14107            0.0
429187  2015      2       19393            14107           35.0
429188  2015      2       19393            14679           99.0
429189  2015      2       19393            14679           23.0
429190  2015      2       19393            14679           20.0

[407663 rows x 5 columns]
```

i wanted to know if there is a way for me to build a dictionary. having the keys my airline ID's (which are repeated multiple times) and the values for the keys being the average of the "ARR_DELAY_NEW" for each different AIRLINE_ID.
It would look something like this:

```
d = {19805:average1; 19393:average2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
avgs=df.groupby('AIRLINE_ID')['ARR_DELAY_NEW'].mean()
avgs=dict(avgs)
```

Comment: Nice, worked perfectly. I researched .groupby but i didn't manage to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = {}
airline_id = df.at[0,'AIRLINE_ID']
total = 0
count = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     if df.at[index,'AIRLINE_ID'] == airline_id:
          total += df.at[index,'ARR_DELAY_NEW']
          count += 1
     else:
          d[airline_id] = total / count
          airline_id = df.at[index,'AIRLINE_ID']
          total = 0
          count = 0

last_id = df.at[len(df)-1, 'AIRLINE_ID']
d[last_id] = total / count
```